# Passing prop to handler messes up routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a handler like so:  `` const addToCartHandler = (id) => { navigate(`/cart/${brand}/${id}?qty=${qty}`)}; ``

and a button component: `<Button onClick={addToCartHandler} className="btn-block w-75" disabled={item.countInStock === 0} type="button">Add to Cart </Button`

When I pass an ID to the `addToCartHandler(someID)`, I get erroneously navigated directly to `/cart/${brand}/${id}?qty=${qty}` when I click on a link that routes to `/product/:brand`

When I don't pass anything and leave off the call `()`, I am accurately routed to the brand page.

Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps, more detail & examples available from ReactJS docs,
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-an-event-handler-like-onclick-to-a-component

How do I pass a parameter to an event handler or callback?
You can use an arrow function to wrap around an event handler and pass parameters:

<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)} />